# Show UNIX directories in Finder?

Tags: finder, unix, macos

I want to know how to show the UNIX directories (/usr, /etc, /dev, ...) in the Finder, but not all the files starting with a '.' (Basically everything you see when you `ls /`)

Everything I've found on it has been outdated and doesn't work on OS X 10.10.

Comment: You should have listed what you have tried!  Have you tried using the `chflags` command?  In a Terminal type `man chflags` and press Enter to see its manage.

Comment: @user3439894 Yes I've tried `chflags nohidden /usr` but it does nothing, I've also tried `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES` but that shows everything, including files starting with '.'

Comment: Okay, I did some testing under OS X Yosemite and the`chflags` command **does** work on `/usr`, `/etc` however it does **not** work on `/dev`.  At this point I did not try other normally hidden directories.  While I do have a workaround nonetheless I like to know why you want to expose these objects that are normally hidden for good reasons and is it all hidden directories or just some of them and if only some of them, which ones?

Comment: @user3439894 You're right, it does work. Turns out Finder put out too far down the page and I had to scroll down... I just want to be able to look for libraries, header files, etc. like you can on Linux